# How to install Ubuntu on the Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: 16.04, raspberrypi

What's the best way to install Ubuntu on a Raspberry Pi 3? I'm finding a few inconsistent links and guides.

I first found [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi), and I installed the `ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img.xz image`, but I found it to be too unstable to use. On every reboot, it had a 50% chance of encountering a kernel panic. I verified this is a problem in the image, and not my hardware, by re-flashing the same SD card with Raspbian, and successfully booting with that. Unfortunately, the image isn't officially supported, and the lone developer working on it seems to have abandoned any further work and bug fixes.

I also found [this page](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/raspberry-pi-2/), which implicitly says it supports the Raspberry Pi 3, but the only linked image is to "raspi2". Will this work on the Pi 3?

That page also links [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/16.04/release/) which lists three different ARM images:

- ubuntu-16.04.1-server-arm64.iso
- ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi2.img.xz
- ubuntu-16.04.1-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi2.img.xz

I also found [this site](https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/download/) which offers a Pi 3 image for Ubuntu 16.

Clearly, the last two are just different versions of the same base image, but will the first work on the Pi 3?

Edit: I've confirmed that the images `ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi2.img.xz` and `ubuntu-16.04.1-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi2.img.xz` do not work with the Pi 3. However, I've confirmed that the image `ubuntu-minimal-16.04-server-armhf-raspberry-pi.img.xz` works perfectly with the Pi 3.

Comment: Try Ubuntu Mate: https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/ For convenience, here's a direct link: https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/ubuntu-mate-16.04-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi.img.xzIf it works, I'll add as an answer.

Comment: I've seen the Mate images, but I'd like to stick to the official distro for LTS updates and compatibility with others packages like ROS that target Ubuntu.

Comment: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-snappy/16.04/current/ubuntu-core-16-pi3.img.xz - this looks like the official one, althouth seems in "beta" currently: https://lists.snapcraft.io/archives/snapcraft/2016-September/001166.html

Comment: I'd recommend against the [Core 16 Snappy image](http://releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/16/ubuntu-core-16-pi3.img.xz), unless you are a developer, and want to play with snaps. It's not intended for users, as there aren't any snaps to use for now. The problem with ubuntu-minimal-16.04-server-armhf-raspberry-pi.img.xz is no kernel updates. The kernel is apparently stuck at 4.1.xxxx, while the official RP kernel is now at 4.4xxx.

Comment: You could use the Developer option for adding "Classic" to the Snappy Core. See https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/raspberry-pi-2-3 & https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/developer-setup

Comment: I have only tested the **Debian 'Raspbian Jessie with desktop'**  version, but I suggest to download and test both **Ubuntu MATE** and the Debian system. See https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads

Answer (score 1):

there are the correct versions of ubuntu desktop and server on rpi's website:

https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/

there you can get their imager that i hope can help

07

edit:

on the piece of software, you have to choose a specific OS through their menu. you can also select usernames passwords and ssh passwords etc. They do have Ubuntu for the RPi3

Comment: This Ubuntu Desktop is actually Debian :)

Answer (score 1):

Installing Ubuntu for the Raspberry Pi 3 is officially done in the following way:

1. Download the [Raspberry Pi Imager tool](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/) for your computer. Have a MicroSD card ready, and insert it into your computer.
2. Start the Raspberry Pi Imager tool and select: "CHOOSE OS", "Other general-purpose OS", "Ubuntu Server 22.04" *(32-bit or 64-bit - 64-bit is recommended, unless you have a particular reason to run 32-bit)*. You can also select Ubuntu Core (again, if you have a specific reason to do so, mostly for developing IoT devices).
3. Select "Choose Storage" and select the MicroSD card you have inserted.
4. Click the "Cog" icon to enter advanced options. Here you can set hostname, username/password and WiFi at your discretion.
5. Click "Write" to flash the SD Card with the Ubuntu image.
6. When it's done, insert the SD Card in your Raspberry Pi, and you can now boot into Ubuntu.
7. An optional step is to install a desktop environment on the Raspberry Pi - please see the [official guide](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#5-install-a-desktop) or [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1425215/1066942).

Link to the [official guide to install Ubuntu Server](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi).

Link to the [official guide to install Ubuntu Core](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi-core) (requires additional setup with an Ubuntu SSO account).

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) instead and then use [BlenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) to flash it to the sd